# React: onChange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, flux, jestjs

Am new to react and am trying to run unit test for a react app using jest,

The app using the Flux pattern and I have already wrote one component "WEATHER" and before move on to another one I wanted to write test for that component and take TDD approach.

My code running fine but the test fail with this error

```
TypeError: tree.props.onChange is not a function
```

The weather component code :

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import api from '../api';
import weatherStore from '../stores/weatherStore';

//read from weather store
let _getState = () => {
    return {weather: weatherStore.returnWeather()};
};

export default class Weather extends React.Component {



    constructor(proporties) {
        super(proporties);

        this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);

        this.state = _getState();

    }
   componentWillUnmount() {
       weatherStore.removeListener('change', this._onChange);
   }
    componentDidMount() {
        api.getWeather();
        weatherStore.on('change', this._onChange);
    }

    _onChange() {
        this.setState(_getState());
    } 

    render() {
        let weatherState = this.state.weather.map(weather => {

            return <div key={weather.id} className="pull-right row">

                        <div>
                            <span>{weather.main.temp} C</span><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>;
        })

        return <div>{weatherState}</div>;
    }
}
```

Where the test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Weather from '../js/components/Weather';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('should render weather temp and city', ()=> {
    const component = renderer.create(
        <Weather />
    );

    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    // manually trigger the callback
    tree.props._onChange();
    // re-rendering
    tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

});
```

Note since am using flow static type checker it always high light this line of code  `this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);`

with error message saying : property '_onChange' property not found in the weather.

Comment: what do you get when `console.log(tree)`?

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: tree.props.onChange is not a function

Have you tried updating your test with:

```
// manually trigger the callback
tree.props._onChange();
```

Note the dash.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the test same error. I have updated the answer

Comment: Can you please post the result of

`console.log(JSON.stringify(tree.props, null, 2));`

Please put this right below the expect(tree) line

Comment: Output is empty object {}

Comment: That means that your function is not available by props. It will seem pretty obvious when you'll have a firmer grasp on React's principles.
Learning by doing is the best learning

Comment: Advice #1: use a strong test suite like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/).
Advice #2: if you get unexpected results, always try to console.log() first

Comment: Well, I can confirm i got my tests working using mocha, and enzyme

Comment: Awesome. So, would you please mind rating my comments as useful?